# How to make the modal scrollbar replacing the body scrollbar temporary without moving its contents to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I created a Modal. Everything went well. When there are lot of contents, a vertical scrollbar will show up.

The problem is if the body page and the modal have both a lot of contents there will be two vertical scrollbars.

Here an example:

```js
function showModal() {
  // Hide Body Scrollbar
  // document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="block";
  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
    //modal.style.display = "none";
    closeModal();
   }
  }
  
 }
 function closeModal() {
  // Show Body Scrollbar
  // document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="none";
 }
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
 .modalContent {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .modal .modalHeader {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .modal .modalHeader span {
  color: #7788C9;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
 }
 .modal .modalHeader .close {
  color: #000;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
 }
 .clear-close{clear:right;display: block;}

 .modal .modalBody {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #000;
  position: static;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .modal .modalFooter {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
 <center>
  <h1>Modal</h1>
  
  <button onClick="showModal()">
   Show Modal
  </button>
  
  
  <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
  <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
  <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
  <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
 </center>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div id="abc" class="modalContent">
   <div class="modalHeader">
    <span>Modal</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" onclick="closeModal()">X</a>
   </div>

   <div class="modalBody clear-close">
    This is the modal content. 
    <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
   </div>
   
   <div class="modalFooter">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeModal()">Close</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've my solutions, but they have up and down:

1) Trying to keep the modal as short as possible. Problem is not everyone has the same screen size. So some people might see 2 scrollbars.

2) In my Javascript code, `document.body.style.overflow` are currently set as a commentary. I uncomment them. When I click Show Modal, it shows 1 scrollbar like I want. But the down is when I click on it, the content behind the modal moves slightly to the right. (When websites is centered)

So, is there a way to show the modal scrollbar only without the body scrollbar and without making the content behind moving slightly to the right and to the left?

- We should see 1 scrollbar only when the modal show up.
- We should not see the content behind the modal moving slightly to the
  right and left when opening and closing.

Note: I'm not allowed to use jQuery

Comment: I'm using the SlimScroll (http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) in Modal-Views for this problem. Works very smooth!

Comment: But without jQuery, is it possible?

Comment: Never done anything without jQuery, therefore it is too comfortable, sorry.